Configuring VS-Code to work with PyBricks not working
I followed the instructions presented in this document but it looks I missed something or things changed since that document was posted.
While walking through the section entitled "Setting up virtual environment", the first inconsistency I found was when attempting to create a terminal (command: "Python: Create Terminal".
In contrast to what is shown in the document, the terminal is open on ".venv"s parent folder.
Next, after stepping into the .venv folder and attempting the next command to install the pybricks package, I got an error message stating the the command pip is not recognized.
I then realized that there is no subfolder scripts at all under the .venv folder.
Any suggestion will be much appreciated.
